# Running Mocha tests on javascript file generated from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

Trying to test a class that has been written in Typescript with Mocha.

The class inherits from a base class.

Since the code was initially written in Typescript (1.7.3) then transpile into javascript (AMD [requireJs] and not commonjs).

All the business object  have the following snippet of code for the inheritance:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
```

Environnement :

- Mocha 2.4.3
- Typescript 1.7.3
- gulp 3.9.0

The tests are launched from gulp :

```
gulp.task("test",function() {
    gulp.src(["../test/test-*.js"],{read:false})
        .pipe(mocha({
            ui:'bdd',
            reporter:"spec",
            globals:{
                should:should
            }
        }))
});
```

test.js

```
describe('Array', function() {
    before(function(done) {
        var MonetaryAmount= undefined;
        require("../PATH/MonetaryAmount", function(ma){
            MonetaryAmount = ma;
            console.log(ma)
            done();
        } )
    });

    describe('Test object creation', function() {
        context('Test constructor', function() {
            it('should not be undefined', function() {
                var newMA = new MonetaryAmount();
                newMA.should.not.be.type("undefined");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I'm running the test I get the following error :

```
$PATH\TO\GULP\FILE>gulp test
    [14:50:23] Using gulpfile $PATH\TO\GULP\FILE\gulpfile.js
    [14:50:23] Starting 'test'...
    [14:50:23] Finished 'test' after 7.76 ms

Array
1) "before all" hook

0 passing (8ms)
1 failing

1) Array "before all" hook:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at __extends ($\PATH\MonetaryAmount.js:4:72)
```

The web application work in the browser, but I'm not sure how to create the test in that context.